# How can i set a dynamic date for a JSON value?

Tags: php, json

Im trying to set a POST request to a file in my website with some data in JSON. There is a value response that needs to be a dynamic date so when the request is made the current date is saved in a custom field. How can i set up the code under "value" so the date is generated?

Have tried things like "variable":{ new Date(), } but can't make it work since always ends displaying the code and not a date, or the code is not validated if i add [ or { , etc.

```
 {
        "version": "v2",
        "content": {
            "messages": [],
            "actions": [{
                "action": "set_field_value",
                "field_name": "bday_reg_date",
                "value": "2019-06-22"
            }, {
                "action": "set_field_value",
                "field_name": "bday_exp_date",
                "value": "2019-06-29"
            }
```

That's the code im basing mine. Everytime i access the file (apparently a .php file), a new date is generated on "value", that date is send and to a custom field called reg_date on another platform. What should be the correct way to get that dynamic value?

Thanks.

Comment: Your code that generates the JSON please

Answer (score 0):

If your are trying to create a new json object in PHP you have to create an array first then use the `json_encode($arr)` function to convert it to json.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

IE:

```
<?php

$dateNow = new DateTime('now');
$dateNextWeek = new DateTime('now');
$dateNextWeek->modify('+1 week');

$arr = [
  'version' => 'v2',
  'content' => [
    'messages' => [],
    'actions' => [
      [
        'action' => 'set_field_value',
        'field_name' => 'bday_reg_date',
        'value' => $dateNow->format('d-m-Y'),
      ],
      [
        'action' => 'set_field_value',
        'field_name' => 'bday_reg_date',
        'value' => $dateNextWeek->format('d-m-Y'),
      ],
    ]
  ]
];

return json_encode($arr);
```

Comment: Not sure if the objects are created in PHP (the file/url does end as PHP), but seems that if put the code in PHP it doesn't work when i test the response, it doesn't take it as a valid format and i can't access the URL contrary as the file im being based to, where i can access the PHP URL. 
Is possible to enclose the PHP like "value": [ <?php .... ]   ?

Comment: You are not in control of the php code? Which code are you using to send the data and what are you expecting back?

Comment: I have an URL that ends on a PHP file that has the code i posted. 
There is a POST request to this URL that takes the data and saves it on users information on another platform. 
Im trying to replicate that code, since if the original urls gets down, my project goes down and i will have no control over this. 
Based on your answer and previous Immortal Dude question, i understand now that i need another PHP file that sends the data to the PHP URL im seeing?Is that correct?

Comment: What are you currently using to create the POST request?

Comment: a block on Manychat called "Get Dynamic Content" https://manychat.github.io/dynamic_block_docs/

Comment: Hmm I have never used that product so I'm not sure how to implement it the way you want. Since it was tagged as php I was assuming you were coding in PHP yourself. Im sorry.

Comment: No problem, actually your code helped me (Thanks!) what i did was to print $arr on another file, so the service could read the json. What im left to figure out is how to send POST back to a webhook url, where the URL is taken from another request.